# How to use loops statements in shell scripting

Tags: bash, unix

I wrote a script to execute a control. In the script, I am checking for an error. If error =200 then again rerun the control after five minutes. Now the script is getting exist irrespective of error. Below is my script.

```
. $HOME/infogix.env
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $0)
INFOGIX=info/IA83/Client/bin/runcp.sh

check_for_errors()
{
if  [ "${1}" -ne "0" ]; then
exit 1
fi
}
$RUNCP_HOME -c $1 IA -entity NGN_MKTG_CNCT_HIST_FILECNT_CE -point FILE_EXTRACT_CP
check_for_errors $?

echo "Processing Complete for ${SCRIPT_NAME}"
exit 0
#EOF
```

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps names are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (see fourth paragraph) for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use. Keep in mind that setting any shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable, so naming conventions apply across both classes.

Comment: The shebang *must* be the first line of your script for it to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually using a loop in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

. "$HOME/infogix.env"
script_name="$(basename "$0")"
info_gix="info/IA83/Client/bin/runcp.sh"

function run_runcp()
{
    $RUNCP_HOME -c "$1" IA -entity NGN_MKTG_CNCT_HIST_FILECNT_CE -point FILE_EXTRACT_CP;
    if [ "$?" -eq 200 ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# If RUNCP_HOME returns 0, then the loop will stop. Otherwise, it will sleep for 5 minutes then continue
while run_runcp "$1"; do
    sleep 300 # Five minutes
done

echo "Processing Complete for ${script_name}"
exit 0
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to fix some of the other issues (ie. missing quotes) while you're here. This answer still has several bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: @Coder_Man :- The loop should work only when the error_core is 200 , because the control will give error code 12 and 16 as well . How this script will check for 200. please let me know.Be

Comment: BTW, the `function` keyword is a bashism that provides no advantage over the POSIX-standard `run_runcp() {` syntax (with no `function` preceding). I'd suggest leaving it out.